# Putting a Spinner inside an onClick

Tags: android, dialog, android-spinner

I have four buttons in an an activity, so I am using an onClick Method.  One of them (that is the issue herEe simply should show a Dialog with two spinners inside.  Here is code:

```
public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId()) {

        case R.id.bAddNew:

        // first button - not related

            break;

        case R.id.bAdvancedSettings:

            // Spinner 1
            plan = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinner1Adapter = ArrayAdapter
                    .createFromResource(this, R.array.paymentplan,
                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            spinner1Adapter
                    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            plan.setAdapter(spinner1Adapter);
            plan.setSelection(0);
            plan.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListenerPlan());

            // Spinner 2
            display = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinner2Adapter = ArrayAdapter
                    .createFromResource(this, R.array.quickview,
                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            spinner2Adapter
                    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            display.setAdapter(spinner2Adapter);
            display.setSelection(0);
            display.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListenerDisplay());

            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ManageDebts.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.advanced);
            dialog.setTitle("Advanced Details");
            dialog.setCancelable(true);

            Button Submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAdvancedSubmit);
            Submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {

                    dialog.dismiss();

                }
            });

break;

// next two buttons
```

}

Here is LogCat I am getting:

```
11-30 09:50:52.305: E/AndroidRuntime(10747): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-30 09:50:52.305: E/AndroidRuntime(10747): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
11-30 09:50:52.305: E/AndroidRuntime(10747):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3597)
11-30 09:50:52.305: E/AndroidRuntime(10747):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
11-30 09:50:52.305: E/AndroidRuntime(10747):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
11-30 09:50:52.305: E/AndroidRuntime(10747):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
11-30 09:50:52.305: E/AndroidRuntime(10747):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-30 09:50:52.305: E/AndroidRuntime(10747):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-30 09:50:52.305: E/AndroidRuntime(10747):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
11-30 09:50:52.305: E/AndroidRuntime(10747):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-30 09:50:52.305: E/AndroidRuntime(10747):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-30 09:50:52.305: E/AndroidRuntime(10747):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-30 09:50:52.305: E/AndroidRuntime(10747):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-30 09:50:52.305: E/AndroidRuntime(10747):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-30 09:50:52.305: E/AndroidRuntime(10747): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-30 09:50:52.305: E/AndroidRuntime(10747):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-30 09:50:52.305: E/AndroidRuntime(10747):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-30 09:50:52.305: E/AndroidRuntime(10747):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3592)
11-30 09:50:52.305: E/AndroidRuntime(10747):    ... 11 more
11-30 09:50:52.305: E/AndroidRuntime(10747): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-30 09:50:52.305: E/AndroidRuntime(10747):    at com.---.---.ManageDebts.onClick(ManageDebts.java:211)
11-30 09:50:52.305: E/AndroidRuntime(10747):    ... 14 more
```

Line 211 is

```
plan.setAdapter(spinner1Adapter);
```

Can anyone see what the problem is?  I have done many dialog's and spinners, but this is the first time together.  Not sure if I just don't know how to do this or if it is just something small I overlooked.

Comment: do you inflate a layout for the `Dialog`?

Comment: isn't that what this does?  `dialog.setContentView(R.layout.advanced);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess here is the problem

```
 Button Submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAdvancedSubmit);
```

replace with

```
 Button Submit = (Button) dialog .findViewById(R.id.buttonAdvancedSubmit);
```

Comment: Thanks.  This did not work though.  The LogCat line trips up before this button is called.

Comment: `Spinner` are in `advanced` ??

Comment: Yes they are, I see, you are correct.  I added `dialog` in front of those and error goes away.  But no Dialog show?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're trying to find the `Spinner` from your `Activity` content view.

Just call:

```
plan = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
```

And for all other views that are in there for the `Dialog`

You have to have called `dialog.setContentView()`, before looking for these views.